# Call Asynctask one after another in my android application

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-asynctask

I have an application that uses Asyncttask but i want to execute two tasks that too after one completes. But i am unable to do that so can you please just give me pseudo code.
here is my Asynctask class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private class getresponse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog pd ;

    private Context _context;

    public getresponse(Context c)
    {
        _context = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

         progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         pd = new ProgressDialog(_context);
            pd.setTitle("Getting JSON details");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            /*String t = finduserjson.substring(
                    finduserjson.indexOf("{"),
                    finduserjson.lastIndexOf(",{"));
            String j = "]}";
            finduserjson = t + j;
            Log.d("FINDUSERJSON", "FINDUSERJSON" + finduserjson);*/
            jsonobject1.put("username", params[0]);
            jsonobject1.put("udid",
                    "A892E0AB-6732-4F42-BEFA-3157315E9EE4");
            socket.emit("setPseudo", jsonobject1);
            socket.emit("findAllUsers", jsonobject1);

            Log.e("TAG",""+ socket.getId());
        } catch (JSONException | MalformedURLException e1) {
             if (pd.isShowing())
                    pd.dismiss();
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



    return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try
        {
            if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

         /*String t = finduserjson.substring(
                    finduserjson.indexOf("{"), 
                    finduserjson.lastIndexOf(",{")); 
            String j = "]}";
            finduserjson = t + j;
            Log.d("FINDUSERJSON", "FINDUSERJSON" + finduserjson);

              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MenuScreen.class);  
                intent.putExtra("onlineuser", onlineuser);
                intent.putExtra("finduser", finduserjson);
                startActivity(intent);*/
        new getresponse111(MainActivity.this).execute();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCancelled();
        pd.dismiss();
    }



}
private class getresponse111 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


    private Context _context;

    public getresponse111(Context c)
    {
        _context = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String t = finduserjson.substring(
                finduserjson.indexOf("{"),
                finduserjson.lastIndexOf(",{"));
        String j = "]}";
        finduserjson = t + j;
        Log.d("FINDUSERJSON", "FINDUSERJSON" + finduserjson);



    return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MenuScreen.class);  
                intent.putExtra("onlineuser", onlineuser);
                intent.putExtra("finduser", finduserjson);
                startActivity(intent);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCancelled();

    }



}
```

Error is following

```
  09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at com.example.socketserver.MainActivity$getresponse111.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:231)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at com.example.socketserver.MainActivity$getresponse111.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Directly asking about the code **so can you please just give me pseudo code.** ..WOW!!!!

Comment: I do not understand what you want to accomplish, I only see 1 async task, not too, do you want to execute 2 instances of the same Asynctask?

Comment: You want pseudocode, so, you get pseudocode, you know, you should properly get your result from AsyncTask in a methode `onTaskComplete` (of an Interface, which your Activity should implement or an extra class, which implements that interface), what ensures, data is available after async Task. How you do it, is calling in `onPostExecute` the `onTaskComplete` of Activity, which called the AsyncTask. A practical Example is here http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/extracting-out-your-asynctasks-into-separate-classes-makes-your-code-cleaner/  Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

**Steps**::

- Just use two AsyncTasks
- Start the first AsyncTask from `onStart()`
- Initiate the second AsyncTask from `onPostExecute()` of the first
  AsyncTask
- So when the first `AsyncTask` is completed the second `AsyncTask` is
  started immideately

---

```
Here is an Example::
```

---

```
    public class FrgLatein extends Fragment {
        //New-Instance
        public static FrgLatein newInstance(){
            Log.d("FrgLatein", "newInstance");
            FrgLatein fragment = new FrgLatein();
            return  fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("FrgLatein", "onCreateView");
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_latein, container, false);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);


            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("FrgLatein", "onActivityCreated");
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            Log.d("FrgLatein", "onStart");
            super.onStart();
            new LongOperation1().execute("");

        }

    private class LongOperation1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                 // Do the Web service long run here
                return "Executed";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
              // Do the UI-task here
              new LongOperation2().execute("");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
              // Do the UI-task here
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
              // Do the UI-task here which has to be done during backgroung tasks are running like a downloading process
            }
        }



 private class LongOperation2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                 // Do the Web service long run here
                return "Executed";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
              // Do the UI-task here
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
              // Do the UI-task here
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
              // Do the UI-task here which has to be done during backgroung tasks are running like a downloading process
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Mehdi ... Hmm ... i also notice you are passing contexts between the `AsyncTasks` .... Its not necessary i think !

Comment: @Mehdi ... Use the debugger tool and find exactly which line you are getting error ! .... That will reduce the complexity of problem

Answer (score 1):

You Async task in onPostExecute of another AsyncTask, I have posted some Psuedo code.

```
class AsyncTask1 extends AsynTask<Void, Void, String>{
       @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //TODO something
            return s;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          // Handle JSON response of your result. 
          //TODO call another AsyncTask
          AsyncTask2.execute();
        }
   }
```

In postExecute of another AsyncTask you can call whatever Activity you need.

```
class AsyncTask2 extends AsynTask<Void, Void, String>{
           @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                //TODO something
                return s;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
              // Handle JSON response of your result. 
              //TODO call Activity

            }
       }
```

Comment: I had understood, he wanted perform that JSON operations after his asyncTask. If he wants to execute 2 different Async Tasks, I would get the result of first one and just then I would execute the second one. Regards

Comment: After performing those operations, Finally another Asynctask can be called.

Comment: ok, then, get properly the result of your first async task as explained in a comment of your first post, in that onTaskComplete you can call the next async Task. You ensure data availability like this if the data from first one would be necessary for the second one. Regards

Comment: Getting error....09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-25 13:00:30.997: E/AndroidRuntime(5906

Comment: For me its working. Make sure you write it in OnPostExecute once all tasks of current AsyncTask is done.

Comment: You are using some socket and all there, Try posting another by telling at which line there is crash

Comment: See i am trying to do substring of following string in my asynctask  {"findAllUsersResponse":[{"id":"IW2djvfuKJMZpafBe1R2","name":"set","udid":"A892E0AB-6732-4F42-BEFA-3157315E9EE4"},{"id":"GQgMcve5oZXWp5fve1SV","name":"desktop","udid":1411632943074},{"id":"7HIWcHimRErtMplSe1Sg","name":"Ya","udid":"A892E0AB-6732-4F42-BEFA-3157315E9EE4"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `onPostExecute()` method. Like,

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try 
        { 
            if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        { 

        } 

     // If you want to call one more AsyncTask then call it here 
     // new AsyncClassName(_context).execute();   Your question is vague, please clarify it. 

       String t = finduserjson.substring(
            finduserjson.indexOf("{"), 
            finduserjson.lastIndexOf(",{")); 
    String j = "]}";
    finduserjson = t + j;
    Log.d("FINDUSERJSON", "FINDUSERJSON" + finduserjson);

      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                MenuScreen.class);  
        intent.putExtra("onlineuser", onlineuser);
        intent.putExtra("finduser", finduserjson);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: Bro i have done it but it gives me error. i have updated in my question

Comment: Is that complete logcat trace?

Comment: Please update your question with actual code you are trying and all the traces of logcat.

Comment: MainActivity.java:231) What is in this line?

Comment: Point out the line number 231

Comment: finduserjson.indexOf("{"),

Comment: Check what is the value in String `finduserjson`

Comment: Are you getting that String from previous AsyncTask?

Comment: No i am not getting from previous task i m getting it from another class.... here is my string  {"findAllUsersResponse":[{"id":"IW2djvfuKJMZpafBe1R2","name":"set","udid":"A892E0AB-6732-4F42-BEFA-3157315E9EE4"},{"id":"Tfftv6cr8GzunUMCe1SR","name":"sfs","udid":"A892E0AB-6732-4F42-BEFA-3157315E9EE4"}]}

Comment: It seems like JSONArray, what do you want to do with that data?

Comment: Send complete thing to next activity and parse the JSON. Do you know how to parse JSONArray?

Comment: I know that but intent is not able to send the string instead it is sending null value from post execute.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your code to onPostExecute method:
This method called after onBackground and from it you can start you another asyncTask or start activity or any others operations.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    String t = finduserjson.substring(
            finduserjson.indexOf("{"),
            finduserjson.lastIndexOf(",{"));
    String j = "]}";
    finduserjson = t + j;
    Log.d("FINDUSERJSON", "FINDUSERJSON" + finduserjson);
    try
    {
        if (pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                MenuScreen.class); 
        intent.putExtra("onlineuser", onlineuser);
        intent.putExtra("finduser", finduserjson);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

[You can read about onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result))

Comment: I am getting error as i have updated my code with error

Comment: try to delete this line super.onPostExecute(result);